# python tkinter why icant use frame.grid_forget()

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to remove a frame from the main page so I tried to use frame.grid_forget() but it gives me this error: _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame" what to do ?

Comment: That error is telling you the widget has been destroyed. You can't call `grid` on a destroyed window. Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple: When you call `window.destroy()`, the window doesn't exist any more. Therefore, you can't call `grid` or `grid_forget()`, because the widget's data is gone.

One suggestion I would make for you to avoid this annoying error would be to use `.withdraw()`. This way, you can still call the widget's functions, and it will only be minimized.

To bring it back up, use `.deiconify()`.